# Can I take 'outer' class Attributes and use them in 'inner' class?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

Can I take 'outer' class Attributes and use them in 'inner' class ?

I want to make an outer class that contains the name and age of a man and the inner class contains the age of a man.... I tried this way but VSC told me that this is a syntax error

I tried to search for a way to inherit from 'father_city' class and I found [this](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/inner-classes-python) but I didn't understand it

```
class father_city:
    
    def __init__(self, city):

        self.city = city


        self.name = 'mark'


    def show_city(self):
        print(f"hello {self.name} you live in {self.city}")

    
    class father_age:

        def __init__(self, age):
            self.age = age


        def show_age(self):
            print(f'hello {father_city('Ny').name} your age is {self.age}')


ob = father_city('Ny')

print(ob.father_age(26).show_age())
```

Comment: Why are you nesting classes? What do you believe this accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your show_age method has a syntax error,when using `'` inside a fstring you should use `"` to surround the string.

```
print(f"hello {father_city('Ny').name} your age is {self.age}")
```